# Trying to use exclude_if on Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to escape a value from a field according to another field, but it never get escaped. Here's a part of my code. However if `'samename'` is true or false, `'res_title'` never get escaped. It always end up in my database. I've also tried with `'unless_if'`, but stil got the same result.

```
return [
    'samename' => 'required|boolean',
    'res_title' => 'exclude_if:samename,false'
    ];
```

So here is how I process the request, I use Postman :

```
{
    "samename": true,
    "res_title": "test"
}
```

Also, here is my controller :

```
public function store(DmLogRequest $req)
{
    $log = new DmLog();
    $log->samename = $req->samename;
    $log->res_title = $req->res_title;

    $log->save();
    return response()->json($log);
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code that shows how you are interacting with this Request and using the input data?

Comment: I've updated my question if you mind having a look please :)) @lagbox

Comment: "The field under validation will be excluded from the request data returned by the `validate` and `validated` methods" ... it does not "exclude" it from the Request inputs directly it only excludes it from the array returned by `validated` or `validate`

Comment: Thank you, I've read it too on Laravel :p I'll go back to my tutorials, thank you for your help.

Comment: also `samename` is `true` and you are saying exclude it if it is `false`, so it won't be excluded from the array returned from `validated`

Comment: " However 'samename' is true or false, 'res_title' never get escaped "

Comment: because it does not exclude it from the request inputs .. it only excludes it from the array returned from `validated` (which you are not calling) ... the term is 'excluded' not 'escaped' ... `$data = $req->validated();`

Comment: All right, I understand way better, I'm giving some try in the same time, I think I start understanding the concept. I've wrote the rules, but I need ->validated() to apply the rules. Isn't ?